# Check table column value is empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to return 0 if my table contains nothing or it has null value. I have only one column called `id` but I don't know why this query is not working.

```
select 
case when  b.id is null or b.id ='' then 0 else b.id end test 
from test b
```

how to get zero if table contains no data or it is being truncated.

Comment: it works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a0d1/1

Comment: Is ID a number or a char field?

Comment: it don't works if u truncate the table. How to do i make query to return zero if table is empty

Comment: if id is int then  ' ' will never gets added to that field.

Comment: SELECT IFNULL(b.id, 0) test FROM test b; this is an easier way to print something else when field is null.